# Force GUI update from UI Thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

In WinForms, how do I force an immediate UI update from UI thread?

What I'm doing is roughly:

```
label.Text = "Please Wait..."
try 
{
    SomewhatLongRunningOperation(); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    label.Text = "Error: " + e.Message;
    return;
}
label.Text = "Success!";
```

Label text does not get set to "Please Wait..." before the operation.

I solved this using another thread for the operation, but it gets hairy and I'd like to simplify the code.

Comment: Running `SomewhatLongRunningOperation()` in another thread is the right answer here.  You shouldn't tie up the UI thread for anything that doesn't directly affect UI.  As for simplifying the code, it's quite possible that you could simplify the use of that other thread.

Comment: Related post - [How do I update the GUI from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561/465053) & [Why won't control update/refresh mid-process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2341731/465053)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

At first I wondered why the OP hadn't already marked one of the responses as the answer, but after trying it myself and still have it not work, I dug a little deeper and found there's much more to this issue then I'd first supposed.

A better understanding can be gained by reading from a similar question: [Why won't control update/refresh mid-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341731/why-wont-control-update-refresh-mid-process)

Lastly, for the record, I was able to get my label to update by doing the following:

```
private void SetStatus(string status) 
{
    lblStatus.Text = status;
    lblStatus.Invalidate();
    lblStatus.Update();
    lblStatus.Refresh();
    Application.DoEvents();
}
```

Though from what I understand this is far from an elegant and correct approach to doing it. It's a hack that may or may not work depending upon how busy the thread is.

Comment: Thanks, it actually works. I re-structured the code to get around this, but your solution (hacky as it may be) is more elegant.

Comment: I was going NUTS with that ! Pfiew !!! Thought that an invalidate call would do... Never would have thought to pack all these call just to get a Label updated. Haky but it works.

Comment: `Refresh()` is equivalent to `Invalidate()` followed by `Update()`, so you're actually doing it twice there.

Comment: Even `.Refresh()` is quite useless, see my answer below. `Application.DoEvents()`is the only command you need, although it should only be used on very simple programs. On the rest, better use real threading (e.g. by using BackgroundWorker).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore. Whether you use all those commands on the object of the form (in my case richtextbox1)  or just  Application.DoEvents(); neither works. I have richtextbox1.Text = "test" and none of those cause the word test to be displayed in the box aside from typing a key which obviously defeats the purpose here. Please update this answer. I would tell the fix if I knew it but I can't figure it out either.

Comment: @codehelp4 - I've seen 10 up-votes and 0 down-votes for this answer since April of this year (2018) for this answer, so I'm inclined to believe that it does still work.

Comment: Using `controlName.Refresh()` allowed me to paint the control more than once during an event.  Thanks!

Comment: All I had to do was Refresh; no invalidate, no update, especially no DoEvents (this caused other problems for me - it seems the Initialize event became recursive if you do this during init).

Comment: Is there a WPF/XAML solution for this, I'm getting Application does not contain a definition for DoEvents

Answer (score 18):

Call `Application.DoEvents()` after setting the label, but you should do all the work in a separate thread instead, so the user may close the window.

Comment: +1, but it is for simple applications it is completely valid to keep things simple by not using background worker thread.  Just set the cursor to an hourglass call Application.DoEvents.

Comment: No, it's not, since the SomeWhatLongRunningOperation is blocking the whole application. Do you like non-responding programs? I don't!

Comment: No I just don't like over-complicating simple applications that simply don't require the overhead of multiple threads.  Windows is a multi-tasking OS, just kick off the task and do some other work done in another app.

Comment: I would argue that the simple application makes for excellent training ground to get things like threading right, so that you don't have to experiment in more critical code. Furthermore, `Application.DoEvents` may introduce interesting issues (that would also occur with threading), such as what happens if the user click a button that triggers the operation again, which it is still running?

Comment: @Frederik, where I work, if you were to do "training exercises" by introducing more complicated code to simple applications you would be quickly given a "kick up the rear".

Comment: @Ash: Have you ever had a look at the thread count after starting a simple .NET forms application? So tell us how you would introduce yourself into multithreaded development if not using a simple excercise? I'm curious.

Answer (score 18):

Call `label.Invalidate` and then `label.Update()` - usually the update only happens after you exit the current function but calling Update forces it to update at that specific place in code.
From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx):

> The Invalidate method governs what gets painted or repainted. The Update method governs when the painting or repainting occurs. If you use the Invalidate and Update methods together rather than calling Refresh, what gets repainted depends on which overload of Invalidate you use. The Update method just forces the control to be painted immediately, but the Invalidate method governs what gets painted when you call the Update method.

Comment: And so, as you can see, `label.Invalidate()` (with no arguments) followed by `label.Update()` is equivalent to `label.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 6):

If you only need to update a couple controls, .update() is sufficient.

```
btnMyButton.BackColor=Color.Green; // it eventually turned green, after a delay
btnMyButton.Update(); // after I added this, it turned green quickly
```

Answer (score 5):

I've just stumbled over the same problem and found some interesting information and I wanted to put in my two cents and add it here.

First of all, as others have already mentioned, long-running operations should be done by a thread, which can be a background worker, an explicit thread, a thread from the threadpool or (since .Net 4.0) a task: [Stackoverflow 570537: update-label-while-processing-in-windows-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/570557/2505186), so that the UI keeps responsive.

But for short tasks there is no real need for threading although it doesn't hurt of course.

I have created a winform with one button and one label to analyze this problem:

```
System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
  label1->Text = "Start 1";
  label1->Update();
  System::Threading::Thread::Sleep(5000); // do other work
}
```

My analysis was stepping over the code (using F10) and seeing what happened. And after reading this article [Multithreading in WinForms](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx) I have found something interesting. The article says at the bottom of the first page, that the UI thread can not repaint the UI until the currently executed function finishes and the window is marked by Windows as "not responding" instead after a while. I have also noticed that on my test application from above while stepping through it, but only in certain cases.

(For the following test it is important to not have Visual Studio set to fullscreen, you must be able to see your little application window at the same time next to it, You must not have to switch between the Visual Studio window for debugging and your application window to see what happens. Start the application, set a breakpoint at `label1->Text ...`, put the application window beside the VS window and place the mouse cursor over the VS window.)

1. When I click once on VS after app start (to put the focues there and enable stepping) and *step through it WITHOUT moving the mouse, the new text is set and the label is updated in the update() function.* This means, the UI is repainted obviously.
2. When I step over the first line, then move the mouse around a lot and click somewhere, then step further, the new text is likely set and the update() function is called, but the UI is not updated/repainted and the old text remains there until the button1_click() function finishes. Instead of repainting, the window is marked as "not responsive"! It also doesn't help to add `this->Update();` to update the whole form.
3. Adding `Application::DoEvents();` gives the UI a chance to update/repaint. Anyway you have to take care that the user can not press buttons or perform other operations on the UI that are not permitted!! Therefore: [Try to avoid DoEvents()!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents), better use threading (which I think is quite simple in .Net).
   But (*@Jagd, Apr 2 '10 at 19:25*) you can omit `.refresh()` and `.invalidate()`.

My explanations is as following: AFAIK winform still uses the WINAPI function. Also [MSDN article about System.Windows.Forms Control.Update method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx) refers to WINAPI function WM_PAINT. The [MSDN article about WM_PAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states in its first sentence that the WM_PAINT command is only sent by the system when the message queue is empty. But as the message queue is already filled in the 2nd case, it is not send and thus the label and the application form are not repainted.

<>joke> Conclusion: so you just have to keep the user from using the mouse ;-) <>/joke>

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
using System.Windows.Forms; // u need this to include.

MethodInvoker updateIt = delegate
                {
                    this.label1.Text = "Started...";
                };
this.label1.BeginInvoke(updateIt);
```

See if it works.

Answer (score 3):

After updating the UI, start a task to perform with the long running operation:

```
label.Text = "Please Wait...";

Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try
    {
        SomewhatLongRunningOperation();
        return "Success!";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error: " + e.Message;
    }
});
Task UITask = task.ContinueWith((ret) =>
{
    label.Text = ret.Result;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

This works in .NET 3.5 and later.

Answer (score 1):

It's very tempting to want to "fix" this and force a UI update, but the best fix is to do this on a background thread and not tie up the UI thread, so that it can still respond to events.

Comment: Overkill, for a simple application it is completely valid to force a UI update.  The minimize/maximize buttons still work, just work on something else.  Why introduce inter thread communication issues?

Comment: I wouldn't call it overkill for a simple application, only overkill if the operation is a really short one. However, he called it a "SomewhatLongRunningOperation". And since people usually only need to do this if the UI will be tied up for a somwhat long period of time, why lock the UI at all? That's what the BackgroundWorker class is for! Can't get much easier than that.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling label.Invalidate()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Think I have the answer, distilled from the above and a little experimentation.

```
progressBar.Value = progressBar.Maximum - 1;
progressBar.Maximum = progressBar.Value;
```

I tried decrementing the value and the screen updated even in debug mode, but that would not work for setting `progressBar.Value` to `progressBar.Maximum`, because you cannot set the progress bar value above the maximum, so I first set the `progressBar.Value` to `progressBar.Maximum -`1, then set `progressBar.Maxiumum` to equal `progressBar.Valu`e. They say there is more than one way of killing a cat. Sometimes I'd like to kill Bill Gates or whoever it is now :o).

With this result, I did not even appear to need to `Invalidate()`, `Refresh()`, `Update()`, or do anything to the progress bar or its Panel container or the parent Form.

Comment: this works because progressBar.Value works differently than label1.Text. Setting the Value property is internally calling something similar to "Update".

Answer (score 1):

myControlName.Refresh() is a simple solution to update a control before moving on to a "SomewhatLongRunningOperation".
From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.update?view=windowsdesktop-6.0
There are two ways to repaint a form and its contents:

1. You can use one of the overloads of the Invalidate method with the Update method.
2. You can call the Refresh method, which forces the control to redraw itself and all its children. This is equivalent to setting the Invalidate method to true and using it with Update.

The Invalidate method governs what gets painted or repainted. The Update method governs when the painting or repainting occurs. If you use the Invalidate and Update methods together rather than calling Refresh, what gets repainted depends on which overload of Invalidate you use. The Update method just forces the control to be painted immediately, but the Invalidate method governs what gets painted when you call the Update method.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with property `Enabled` and I discovered a `first chance exception` raised because of it is **not thread-safe**.
I found solution about "How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?" here https://stackoverflow.com/a/661706/1529139 And it works !

Answer (score 0):

When I want to update the UI in "real-time" (or based on updates to data or long running operations) I use a helper function to "simplify" the code a bit (here it may seem complex, but it scales upward very nicely). Below is an example of code I use to update my UI:

```
    // a utility class that provides helper functions
    // related to Windows Forms and related elements
    public static class FormsHelperFunctions {

        // This method takes a control and an action
        // The action can simply be a method name, some form of delegate, or it could be a lambda function (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions)
        public static void InvokeIfNeeded(this Control control, Action action)
        {

            // control.InvokeRequired checks to see if the current thread is the UI thread,
            // if the current thread is not the UI thread it returns True - as in Invoke IS required
            if(control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // we then ask the control to Invoke the action in the UI thread
                control.Invoke(action);
            }
            // Otherwise, we don't need to Invoke
            else
            {
                // so we can just call the action by adding the parenthesis and semicolon, just like how a method would be called.
                action();
            }
        }

    }

    // An example user control
    public class ExampleUserControl : UserControl {

        /*
            //
            //*****
            // declarations of label and other class variables, etc.
            //*****
            //




            ...
        */

        // This method updates a label, 
        // executes a long-running operation, 
        // and finally updates the label with the resulting message.
        public void ExampleUpdateLabel() {

            // Update our label with the initial text
            UpdateLabelText("Please Wait...");

            // result will be what the label gets set to at the end of this method
            // we set it to Success here to initialize it, knowing that we will only need to change it if an exception actually occurs.
            string result = "Success";

            try {
                // run the long operation
                SomewhatLongRunningOperation(); 
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                // if an exception was caught, we want to update result accordingly
                result = "Error: " + e.Message;
            }

            // Update our label with the result text
            UpdateLabelText(result);
        }

        // This method takes a string and sets our label's text to that value
        // (This could also be turned into a method that updates multiple labels based on variables, rather than one input string affecting one label)
        private void UpdateLabelText(string value) {

            // call our helper funtion on the current control
            // here we use a lambda function (an anonymous method) to create an Action to pass into our method
            // * The lambda function is like a Method that has no name, here our's just updates the label, but it could do anything else we needed
            this.InvokeIfNeeded(() => {

                // set the text of our label to the value
                // (this is where we could set multiple other UI elements (labels, button text, etc) at the same time if we wanted to)
                label.Text = value;
            });
        }

    }
```