# How to process Google Vision API one by one and not in a block?

Tags: c#, loops, google-vision

I got a problem when using the Google Vision API.
I'm looping the process, to analyze several pictures, but when I print the results, all is coming in a block after 5 minutes of process, but I wanted to know if it's possible to start the program and make it print the results after each picture analyzis ?

Here's my code for the algorithm :

```
bool space = false;
        // var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\sequence\\n" + i + ".jpg");
            var image = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.Image.FromFile(path);
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            var response = client.DetectLabels(image);
            CropHintsAnnotation confidence = client.DetectCropHints(image);

        bool car = false;
        bool vehicle = false;
        bool land = false;
        int score = 0;
        //System.IO.Directory

        foreach (var annotation in response)
        {
            textBox1.Text += annotation.Description + "\r\n";
            textBox1.Text += "Score : " + annotation.Score + "\r\n";
            vehicle = !annotation.Description.Equals("vehicle");
            car = !annotation.Description.Equals("car");
            land = !annotation.Description.Equals("land vehicle");

            if (car == false)
            {
                score += 1;
                //textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?       " + car + "\r\n\r\n";
            }
            else if (vehicle == false)
            {
                score += 1;
                //textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?       " + vehicle + "\r\n\r\n";
            }
            else if (land == false)
            {
                score += 1;
                //textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?       " + land + "\r\n\r\n";
            }
            else if (annotation.Description.Equals("asphalt"))
            {
                score += -20;
                //textBox1.Text += "\r\nEmpty ?  True \r\n\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                score += 0;
            }
        }
        if ( score > 0)
        {
            //textBox1.Text += "The parking space is taken \r\n\r\n";
            space = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //textBox1.Text += "The parking space is empty \r\n\r\n";
            space = false;
        }
        return space;
```

I'm looping this with a foreach(Image file in Directory).

Any ideas to help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: `all is coming in a block after 5 minutes of process` Which line of code is taking 5 minutes?

Comment: If I uncomment the writing lines, it's the TextBox1.text += annotation.Description; 
and the line that prints the score, both are printed at the end of the process

Comment: It looks much better ! 
It's close to what I want, but it's enough, thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you update `textBox1.Text`, the UI will not [update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341731/why-wont-control-update-refresh-mid-process) since the UI thread is busy doing the calculation.

As such, you need to call `textBox1.Refresh()` or `Application.DoEvents()` after updating `textBox1.Text`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation ! That worked.