# Part of code doesn't execute without delay

Tags: c#

My app detect is ip changed or not. If ip is different than previous it saves new ip to file. Seems pretty easy.

Delay function:

```
public void MyDelay(int milliseconds)
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= (long)milliseconds)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

Button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;

    while (true)
    {
        while (true)    //force obtain new_ip
        {

            try

            {
                new_ip = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");

            }

            catch
            {
                MyDelay(1000);
                continue;

            }
            break;


        }


        if (old_ip != new_ip)
        {
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\users\pc\Desktop\ip.txt", new_ip + "\r\n");
            old_ip = new_ip;
            MessageBox.Show("New ip saved");
        }
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;

    }
 }
```

The thing is if I left the code like this the part: `pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;` is not going to execute.

I have to change from this:

```
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
```

To this:

```
pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
MyDelay(1);
```

And now picturebox colour is changing. Why does that Delay repair that? If I put MessageBox insted of Picturebox, problem does not even exist. It work as a charm without MyDelay too. So what is the point?

Another question: it should check the ip every 1 second. So why when I change the ip I have to wait about 5 second for change detection? It should save new ip after 1 second when connection appears, but it takes about 5 second to recognize change

Comment: We can't tell you why `MyDelad` causes a behavior change unless you show us the code for `MyDelad`. Also, WebClient is a disposeable class, you should be disposing it after use.

Comment: and are you running this on the main or background thread??

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited first post.

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement some proper threading / background workers.

Comment: exactly what I thought. the problem lies on Application.DoEvents(); Try replacing your delay with this line and it should work

Comment: @Steve with what line?

Comment: @FirstStep replace MyDelay(1) with Application.DoEvents();

Comment: @Steve what about his `MyDelay(1000)` then? Maybe `Thread.Sleep(1000)` is safe here

Comment: @FirstStep I would say its bad code but it won't affect the result

Comment: It is a grossly inappropriate way to call `pictureBox1.Update()`.  [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never create an endless `while (true)` in a button click which blocks the gui for updating. Thats why your `PictureBox` isn't repainted (but the code is executed). If you place your sleep there *(containing `Application.DoEvents()`)*, the paint messages are handled and your `PictureBox` is repainted. But still the GUI thread is blocked.

Using the `Application.DoEvents()` this way is **bad practice**, because other buttons/formcloses are also handled here which makes your application very unstable. **So get rid of the Application.DoEvents()..**

Use a `Timer` instead to check the site for your external IP!

---

Something like: **PSEUDO**

```
public class Form1: Form
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer = new Timer(.....);
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        // etc!!!
    }

}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string new_ip;
    try
    {
        new_ip = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.ipify.org");

    }
    catch 
    { 
        return;
    }

    if (old_ip != new_ip)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\users\pc\Desktop\ip.txt", new_ip + "\r\n");
        old_ip = new_ip;
        MessageBox.Show("New ip saved");
    }
    else
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing all your work in the main thread. Also the UI is being updated in the main thread. This means that you're not allowing the UI to update itself in any way.

When you call your delay function it calls `Application.DoEvents()` which lets the UI to update itself.

You should refactor the code to use a timer,  asynchronous methods or a background worker thread so that the UI can stay responsive.

Answer (score 0):

inside a snipped .net cannot update the interface, you can use `Application.DoEvents()` to solve the problem. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360944/force-gui-update-from-ui-thread) can help further.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your intentions correctly, you can try async await (not sure why it requires a while loop and try catch to get the result of the url though):

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;

        var newIp = await GetIpAsync();

        if (oldIp != newIp)
            pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetIpAsync()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await httpClient.GetStringAsync(@"https://api.ipify.org");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added while loop, because I couldnt obtain ip when it was changing to another one.